# OpenGL Shaders Dont Draw

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, glfw, glew

So recently I started watching a udemy curse but when I got to the point with shaders I got a problem with comes from the line when making the shaders or defining them:

```
#include iostream

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include GL/glew.h

#include GLFW/glfw3.h

const GLint WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;

//here start the shaders def/creation
const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = 
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout ( location = 0 ) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main( )\n"
"{\n"
"gl_Position = vec4( position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0 )\n"
"}";

const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = 
"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main( )\n"
"}\n"
"color = vec4( 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f );\n"
"}";
//here it ends

//more code down here
//....
//....
```

and after that what I get in the console ( the other code gets those error lines on the cmd ) is:

ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED
0(6) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' at token "}"

ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED
0(4) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' at token "}"

ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED

### Vertex info

> 0(6) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' at token "}"
>   (0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link

### Fragment info

> 0(4) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' at token "}"
>   (0) : error C2003: incompatible options for link

I know its not a problem with supporting shaders because I can actually run 3.0 shaders, whan can be in the code where I define the shaders?

EDIT:
Okay sorry if I bothered someone with the question but the reason is that
on line 16
the wrong was this:
`"gl_Position = vec4( position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0 )\n"`

and the right
`"gl_Position = vec4( position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0 );\n"`

yes this symbol ; XD

and at line
23 
the wrong was `"}\n"`
and the right `"{\n"`
this was just miss clicked 
sorry to bother

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: A semicolon (`;`) is missing after `gl_Position = vec4( position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0 )`

Comment: ....-_- if that works

Comment: okay half of it is done it may be another semicolon or something

Comment: You have to use a open curved bracket `{` in the fragment a shader after  `void main( )` insted of a closed one `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vertex shader is missing a semicolon, and your fragment shader has the wrong brace opening up the `main` function.

```
const GLchar *vertexShaderSource = 
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout ( location = 0 ) in vec3 position;\n"
"void main( )\n"
"{\n"
//=============================================Mistake is here↓
"gl_Position = vec4( position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0 )\n"
//===============================================================
"}";

const GLchar *fragmentShaderSource = 
"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"void main( )\n"
//↓Mistake======================================
"}\n"
//==============================================
"color = vec4( 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f );\n"
"}";
```

Fix those two errors, and your code should work.

Also, the only explicit newline you need is the first one after the `#version` directive. They'll get removed during the compilation stage, just like in C or C++. They *might* make debugging easier if you dump the shader code to the console, but they don't impact the behavior or performance of your code.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I started writing the answer before I'd seen all the comments. Either way, you're not supposed to answer questions in the comments for that exact reason.

Comment: I recommend to use [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). The issue is off-topic because it is a simple typographical error.

Comment: thanks that you took the time to answer and I finally got it to work before you said it but still thank you